# This may sound very naive and even offensive, but why does it matter what exactly happened long ago, and why try to spread a religion?

Tags: missions, war, gospel, spiritual-warfare, missionary

I was born and raised in Sweden. I grew up with "kinda" Christian parents. However, I can't remember ever going to a church except when somebody had died or got married. I couldn't tell you which of the numerous "branches" that they believed in, but that's sort of at the core of my question: why exactly does it matter?

I realize and recognize that it *does* clearly matter to an enormous amount of people.

I just don't understand **why** exactly.

Why is it of such importance that other people also believe the exact same set of ancient stories, and interpret them in the same manner, as yourself?

Frankly, as cozy and nice as Christianity can be, I would not feel any sorrow if everyone around me were, instead of Jesus and God, referring to Thor and Oden. In practice, what I like about religion is the concept of unity within a people. Having structure and tradition and recurring events, etc. Some common set of rules which bind a people together and empower it against the outside world.

Note that I'm not saying that peoples should be fighting or going to war to somehow force (or even attempt to convince peacefully) each other about how "they are right". This is also at the core of my world view. I don't understand the futile struggle to travel to Africa (for example) and tell them about our Jesus and God and how they should be living. It's frankly insulting to me. I wish that Christians would never have tried to go on "missions" to "spread the faith", but rather keep it as local as possible.

As somewhat of an "outsider", although still definitely not an Atheist, it seems absurd to me the amount of time, efforts and sorrows are expended arguing and fighting with each other about religions, which can be seen as a metaphor for races, and the belief (no pun intended) that one can "turn" somebody into a Christian (or any other religion, for that matter) by convincing them with arguments. Or that this is meaningful even if it is possible.

I suspect that you will respond:

> Well, in so-and-so page of the Bible, Some Person said so-and-so, so that's why we try to spread the gospel!

I don't mean to offend anyone, and I find the Bible fascinating in many ways, but at the end of the day, what's the end goal of trying to spread a religion/faith/world view to people who are fundamentally incompatible and even violently opposed to hearing what some White Christian tells them, since they already have their own views and traditions locally?

I'm truly not "taking any sides". I just wish that Christians in particular would not try to push their faith (which appears to vary wildly between the numerous "branches") onto people who are just as disinterested in "becoming Christians" or "letting Jesus into their lives" as you would be if a Muslim told you to start slaughtering animals according to the Halal method, or told you that you can only go to Heaven/Valhalla if you believe in the Nordic mythology.

I hope that my point is coming across clearly and that it doesn't offend anyone. I'm genuinely trying to understand why it's such an important thing for Christians to promote their, what amounts to, traditions and rites, toward other people.

Even just trying to convince another Christian of a different branch that what they grew up with is "wrong" is an exercise in futility and appears, to me, almost as if the people trying to do so are actively "picking a fight". In either case, that's what inevitably happens when you tell somebody (or imply) that they are wrong and you are right; they just become stubbornly convinced that their way was right all along and that these external people are trying to sell them something which they have zero interest in.

Would it really be out of the question to simply have your branches and churches and do what you wish in there and if somebody shows interest, they can be invited to join, but this isn't some "end goal" or "the overall purpose" of gathering and believing a certain branch of Christianity (or any religion)?

Comment: Hi, this question, if asked of "all Christianity" is pretty broad and not all Christian groups do what you describe. I'm not sure how to improve the question as stated, but it might be a good start to edit it to ask which Christian faith traditions proselytize and why.

Comment: hi, I'd say 'welcome' but... you already feel welcome don't you? Sadly, I wonder if you've broken the record for the quickest closed Q! It's an important Q that I guess it going to be asked somewhere else now - oh well, our loss. There *are* reasonable answers, but Xianity is a mess of differing, oblique views that sometimes don't even come from the bible! Again, you are right to ask - sadly maybe not here. Thx for asking anyway!

Comment: Alot can be explained through economics, think of the church as a business. Like a ceo’s vision it will pretend it’s seeking the best interest of consumers (read morality) but in fact it only seeks profit (to shareholders). A business must continue expanding ad infinitum - in order to sustain profits. Historically there was a tithing paid by each member, think of it like your netflix subscription. You convert new subscribers by spreading the word.

Comment: Various Christian groups have many various reasons for preaching. They want to bring honor to God, to obey Jesus's command to preach, and to show love to their neighbor. The crux of your question though seems to be that Christians genuinely believe that God is a real person  and that God wants people to have a relationship with him based on things that are true, otherwise our worship is in futile. (John 4:24)

Comment: Two quick reasons why Christians try to convince others: 1) Christians believe that Christ is the fullness of revelation; all truths necessary for salvation are contained in His teaching. It is a loss for a person to not know Christ. 2) Christ commanded us to evangelize -- "Go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, teaching them to obey everything I have commanded you."

Comment: If you are convinced that evolution is a 'thing', then there is no need for a 'Designer'. If there is no designer in your world view, then it doesn't matter - don't worry about when the world will end or what will happen to you. We understand that it is God's (the Designer) responsibility alone to introduce Himself to you - maybe  thru a Christian. He loves the creation He has made and has had a plan in place to rescue it all from the bad place it is- when He does that you will be included and you will meet Him then. We're *fortunate* to know of Him now - not because we are better than you.

Comment: Why on earth was this question closed? It poses a genuine question, it is well thought out, well put, and appears to have a lot of effort put into it. It is not unanswerable and though it is broad, it has to be given that this describes most religions. Just makes no sense to me that it is closed.

Comment: @IanMacintosh the close reason is visible to the OP and people with rep enough to open and close the question.  We have specific criteria for asking questions that are open to multiple faith traditions.  Anybody who knows anything about Christianity knows that Baptists and Mormons would have a wildly different answer for this question.  It might all be rooted in the great commission at the end of Matthew, but it's up to individual interpretation to give an answer.

Comment: Since this isn't accepting answers... because *it would be immoral to *not* evangelize. The message of Christianity is that humans are sinful and stand condemned of a horrible fate, but God (through Christ) wants to rescue us from this fate. To *not* share this message is worse than standing by while someone is maimed or killed when one could have easily prevented it. (Worse because the comparison is of a temporal fate versus an eternal fate.) Disagreements about doctorine ultimately come down to much the same reason.